# storing data picked up from php file in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a php file that runs a simple jquery script:

```
var text = $(".hide").text();
```

I was wondering how I could store this data when I redirect to other pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it into [a cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). Write it, leave the page, then read your own cookie when you get to the next page.

Or you could POST it to another PHP script, and store it in a session variable. In jQuery, it would look something like this

```
$.post("my_other_script.php", { text: "my piece of text"} );
```

my_other_script.php would be

```
<?php $_SESSION['text'] = $_POST['text']; ?>
```

Here is the [jquery page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) documentation for it.

Comment: could I then store the _session variable to another variable?

Comment: and what about session_start()?

Comment: yes, definitely session_start(), which must be at the top of your script, or at least before the script has sent any headers to the browser. So try `<?php session_start();$_SESSION['test']=$_POST['text'];?>` to put the text into the session, then to fetch it out later, `<?php session_start(); $text = $_SESSION['text']?>`

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the value to a hidden form field, then either pass the value around as a form/query-string variable or save it away to a database.

```
$('#hidden_form_field_id').val(text);
```

Alternatively, if it's only a small amount of data then you could save it as a cookie.